# How can I pass a variable from Lightning Flow to LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

The below link have enough information about embedding a LWC in Lightning flow but nothing about passing a variable value to LWC.

https://unofficialsf.com/adding-lightning-web-components-to-flow-screens/

For example:- 
I have a variable in Lightning Flow called '**NewRecord**'. The below LWC .js not fetching the value from Flow.

---

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class TakeMeToClonedOrder extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

@api NewRecord;
@api Message;

navigateToOrder() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
         type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.NewRecord,
                objectApiName: 'Order',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Do you have all the other targetConfig properties set?

Comment: yes, it looks like below.
<targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="NewRecord" type="String"/>
            <property name="Message" type="String"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry my bad, the issue is resolved. I missed to pass the value in Flow Screen -> LWC component. [image]